# Working with two arrays where one array's values match the other array's keys

Tags: php, arrays

I saw another question on a similar matter but my issue appears to be distinct.

I have two arrays:

Array #1:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Baby/Juvenile
    [2] => Bedding
    [3] => Room Decor
    [4] => Bath & Potty
    [5] => Feeding
    [7] => Furniture
    [8] => Bath
    [9] => Towels
    [10] => Shower Curtains
)
```

Array #2

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 9
)
```

I would like to compare these arrays and pull the key/value pairs from the first array based on the values in the second array. My desired output is:

```
   Array
(
    [5] => Feeding
    [7] => Furniture
    [9] => Towels
)
```

I played around with various array functions but can't seem to figure this out, any tips would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A combination of [array_intersect_key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) after doing [array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) on the second array: so `$result = array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2));`

Comment: Although this is PHP it still does not have a magical function for every problem :-) You will need to develop this. @Mark Baker gave you almost all of it...

Comment: Great, I am beginner/intermediate I did not know about array_flip()! Thanks!

Comment: It's also a very simple `foreach` loop, you don't have to use built-in functions for everything.

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling these arrays are actually database data that can be better retrieved with a proper DB query. SELECT id, name FROM categories WHERE id IN(5, 7, 9)

Comment: The arrays are from two separate tables in our db and we already have functions on the page calling the data from our db so it's just a question of organizing the data in the manner in which I want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $array_one = array
    (
        '1' => 'Baby/Juvenile',
        '2' => 'Bedding',
        '3' => 'Room Decor',
        '4' => 'Bath & Potty',
        '5' => 'Feeding',
        '7' => 'Furniture',
        '8' => 'Bath',
        '9' => 'Towels',
        '10' => 'Shower Curtains'
    );

    $array_two = array
    (
        '1' => 5,
        '2' => 7,
        '3' => 9
    );

    foreach($array_two as $value)
    {
        $result[$value] = $array_one[$value];
    }

    var_dump($result);

?>
```

will output

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  string(7) "Feeding"
  [7]=>
  string(9) "Furniture"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "Towels"
}
```